# Problems Installing Metasploit Framework on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu, rubygems, metasploit

I have encountered 3 problems while following [this guide](http://www.darkoperator.com/installing-metasploit-in-ubunt/) to installing Metasploit Framework on Ubuntu and Debian:

1) After installing proper version of ruby, there is a command given for installing Ruby libraries: `sudo gem install bundler`. When I typed that in and hit enter, it says "command not found". After some researching on the internet, I decided to remove `sudo` and try again. So I've entered `gem install bundler` and it worked fine. Will this cause any problems?

2) After installing Metasploit Framework, there is a command given to install the required gems and versions:

```
cd metasploit-framework
bundle install
```

But when I tried that, I got this error:

> rbenv: version '2.1.6' is not installed

I really don't know what to do next (But I moved on).

3) Probably due to the previous problems, in the end when I executed `msfconsole` command, it said

> could not find rake-10.4.2 in any of the sources.
>
> run bundle install to install the missing gems

But the bundle install doesn't help either, because when I run that it says

> Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/directory

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** When I asked the person himself who had written the guide, regarding this, he told me to select the version of ruby I had just installed with either rebind or RVM before installing bundler, and then to run the bundle install. Could you please list the commands to do so? I am really new to Linux!

Comment: I am not using RVM but rbenv (the other ruby version control tool which I think is superior to RVM), but you can select ruby version by 'rvm install 2.1.2' and then 'rvm 2.1.2' for setting ruby version in current session or 'rvm --default 2.1.2' for permanent version selection. Please reopen terminal (open new terminal) to test the switch.

Answer (score 2):

step 1 :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

step 2 :

Install dependent packages

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libreadline-dev libssl-dev libpq5 libpq-dev libreadline5 libsqlite3-dev libpcap-dev openjdk-7-jre git-core autoconf postgresql pgadmin3 curl zlib1g-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev vncviewer libyaml-dev curl zlib1g-dev
```

step 3 :

Install Ruby

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
echo "source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
rvm install 2.1.6
rvm use 2.1.6 --default
ruby -v
```

step 4 :

Install and configure postgresql

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql

sudo -s
su postgres

createuser msf -P -S -R -D
createdb -O msf msf
exit
```

Step 5 :

Install Metasploit Framework

```
cd /opt
sudo git clone https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework.git
sudo chown -R `whoami` /opt/metasploit-framework
cd metasploit-framework
cd metasploit-framework
sudo bash -c 'for MSF in $(ls msf*); do ln -s /opt/metasploit-framework/$MSF /usr/local/bin/$MSF;done'
```

Still if you are facing any issue, you can download the iso or vm image from kali [wesbite](https://www.kali.org/downloads/)

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem in kali after install metasploit-framework, and i can't run msfconsole. I solved the problem using the following method:
At change your directory to `/usr/share/metasploit-framework:`

```
    cd /usr/share/metasploit-framework
```

and after that, install bundler with gem:

```
    gem install bundler
```

then:

```
    bundle install
```

at the end you need to update:

```
    gem update --system
```

and it will work!

Answer (score -1):

This command fixes it:

```
apt-get install ruby2.1-dev &&\
apt-get install libsqlite3-dev &&\
bundle install
```

What it does: install ruby development items